# Failed to fetch full profile details from LinkedIn API

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I tried to fetch full profile details from LinkedIn API. I referred a sample app also. In my app I tried,

```
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_FULL_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION,  nil] state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {
    [self.delegate didSuccessfullyLogIntoLinkedIn];
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    [self.delegate fetchingFailedWithError:error];
}];
```

This code gives me an error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (LISDKAuthError error 5.)

But in the sample app which is provided by the LinkedIn, This same code is working. I went through my app authentications. It has only following fields. I think the problem is, In this list there is no `r_fullprofile` field.

[image]

Is this the problem? Is it possible to add `r_fullprofile` field to this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although basic access gives you only 4 fields, an answer is "Yes, it is possible". If you subscribe to [LinkedIN Partnership Programs](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs).